# How can I get title, and description of website without using UIWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to make URL preview, such as in this picture - 
[image]

So, I get image of website using google favicons.
But I don't understand how can I get the title and description of the web-page.
I know a good library `URLEmbeddedView` and it works great!.
But I want to write my own.
I found many similar questions on stackoverflow, but there are no answers that describe how to get website title without `UIWebView`.

Comment: Can you give me suggestions, how you did implementation for this requirement, presently,  I am also looking for same solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using stock API, you can do the following:

```
- (void)getSiteHtml
{
    NSURLSession *session = NSURLSession.sharedSession;
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.stackoverflow.com"]
           completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
               NSString *htmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
               NSLog(@"http string: %@", htmlString);
           }];
    [dataTask resume];
}
```

This code should be run in background session of course.

You will get back a string like this for StackOverflow:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Stack Overflow</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=4f32ecc8f43d">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon image_src" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a">
    <link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="Stack Overflow" href="/opensearch.xml">
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
    <meta name="twitter:domain" content="stackoverflow.com"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />

    <meta property="og:image" itemprop="image primaryImageOfPage" content="http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded&a" />
    <meta name="twitter:title" property="og:title" itemprop="title name" content="Stack Overflow" />
    <meta name="twitter:description" property="og:description" itemprop="description" content="Q&amp;A for professional and enthusiast programmers" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://stackoverflow.com/"/>

    
    
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=b84e3ec1d0b3"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/all.css?v=ef9c49b839e0">

    <link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="Feed of recent questions" href="/feeds">
    

    <script>
```

You must then parse the string and especially the `<head>` section to look for the `<title>` entry, the `<link >` to the `shortcut icon` and the `<meta>` `twitter:description` to get the information you want, without needing a UIWebView.

That can be done with a XML parser for instance.

Comment: @Sergei R. Can I know how you did that and present I am also looking for same requirement.

Comment: You can parse HTML nodes with XML parser as it is a Markup Language (as SGML too or XML), until you find `<head>` node, then parse subnodes for `<title>` and get its content. No detailled example, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a HTML string using API call for webpage. Use some [third party AP](https://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios)I to parse HTML string and gather required information.

```
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39526606/objective-c-how-can-i-get-title-and-description-of-website-without-using-uiw"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [op setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
    {
        NSString* htmlString = [operation responseString]
        // parse HTML string to gather required information.
    }
```