# iOS Share Extension, get title of shared Item

Tags: ios, swift, ios8-share-extension, share-extension

Does anyone know if it is possible to access the title of a shared item in a share extension.
I know that it is possible to get title and some other attributes by JavaScript. The problem is I want to get the title of items shared from the YouTube App for example. In the Image below it would be the string "Welcome G2.."

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is only possible by supplying URL as shared item to the `UIActivityViewController`. The header will configure itself with appropriate icon, title and domain. It looks like the example you have provided, YouTube app, uses exactly that.

**UPDATE:** to retrive title you can use URLSession, try [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39532184/8160613).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My problem is not to configure the title, I want to access the title in a share extension.

Comment: It is present in the `inputItems[0].userInfo[NSExtensionItemAttributedContentTextKey]` when there is only 1 attachment and that attachment is URL